# jenkins_home path to media ubuntu permission issue

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, jenkins

My jenkins is giving me error when I am changing the default JENKINS_HOME to my location in ubuntu.

```
Unable to create the home directory ‘/media/mysystem/Data/Jenkins’. This is most likely a permission problem.
```

I had edited this file "Jenkins" inside /etc/default folder and changed the jenkins home but when I start the jenkins I am getting the above error message.

I also tried giving full permission to my media using -

```
cd /media/mysystem/Data/
sudo chmod -R -v 777 *
```

but no luck

Here mysystem is my username and Data is the media name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the jenkins user's home directory by modifying configure file.

```
vim /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

Change `$JENKINS_HOME` variable.And then create the folder and use `chown` command to change file owner.

```
mkdir -p /media/mysystem/Data/Jenkins

cd /media/mysystem/Data/Jenkins
cp -Rf /var/lib/jenkins .
chown -R jenkins:jenkins *

service jenkins start (/etc/init.d/jenkins start)
```

Usually,you can just change the `$JENKINS_HOME` and restart.

Hope this helps.